# Connect to SQL Server Compact database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard, and I need to open a SQL Server Compact database file, but that option is disabled. I already installed SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 and also tools.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use my free "SQL Server Compact Toolbox" available as an SSMS extension, Visual Studio extension or standalone app to connect to SQL Server Compact database file.